# Scaling an ImageView when the soft keyboard opens

Tags: java, android, layout

I'm creating a tabbed activity. As long as the first tab is selected, the soft keyboard should be visible. I achieved that by adding this line to my manifest file in the activity tag:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
```

As the keyboard opens, the space for the layout shrinks. The most space is occupated by an ImageView. I want it to shrink with the layout size to allow the other 2 views (which should remain the same size) to fit on the screen. However, although the soft input mode is set to `adjustResize`, the ImageView keeps its size after the keyboard opens. Here's a comparison of the current layout and the one I want to achieve (the ImageView is the red rectangle):
[comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzu2m.png)

My fragment's layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".DataInputFragment"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:src="@drawable/image"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/input_label_text"/>

        <namespace.InputEditText
            android:id="@+id/input_edit_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            <requestFocus/>
        </namespace.InputEditText>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/submit"
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

My activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/TabLayout">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tabItem"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/tab_text_1" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tabItem2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/tab_text_2" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</LinearLayout>
```

How to force the ImageView to resize according to the screen size to make all of the views fit on the screen?

[EDIT]: My attempt to create a ConstraintLayout, which didn't solve the problem (the ImageView still keeps its original size):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".DataInputFragment">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:src="@drawable/image"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/input_label"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/input_label_text"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/img"/>

    <namespace.InputEditText
        android:id="@+id/input_edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/input_label">
        <requestFocus />
    </namespace.InputEditText>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/submit"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/input_edit_text"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created an Android Project from scratch on Android Studio 4.0, using the "Tabbed Activity" template and [uploaded it to GitHub](https://github.com/Gryzor/ImageAutoResized).

I've had no issues with the resize taking place when the activity is resized.

#### What Did I change?

1. In the [manifest.xml](https://github.com/Gryzor/ImageAutoResized/blob/master/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml) I added `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`
2. I modified the default [layout for the fragment in the tab](https://github.com/Gryzor/ImageAutoResized/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_main.xml) to include an `ImageView` (called `imageToShrink`) and an `EditText` (called `editLayout`).
3. I left the existing TextView untouched, except that since it's at the top, I made it the HEAD of the vertical Chain, and gave it a 0.0 BIAS to be aligned at the top, rather at the center.

When you tap on the *cyan* EditText at the bottom, the keyboard pops (I made it number only so it's even taller) and you can see how the image is re-drawn after its new size is recomputed.

This is how it looks when it opens: (beautiful color palette!)

[image: image before the keyboard]

And this is how it looks when I tap the "edit field" to pop the keyboard:

[image: image after the keyboard is open]

Answer (score 1):

your `ImageView` should not have `wrap_content` attributes, because it will always have constant size and wont be able to resize automatically. I would suggest using `ConstraintLayout` and use `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio`. Other option is use `LinearLayout` `weight` (not recommending).

Ant third option is to detect when keyboard is visible, when not with `ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener` and do stuff programmaticaly.

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DataInputFragment">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:src="@drawable/image"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="3:1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/input_label"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/input_label_text"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/img" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input_edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/input_label">

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/submit"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/input_edit_text" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. Could you please help me with doing that with the ConstraintLayout way? I made changes to my layout according to your suggestions, but the result is still the same. I pasted my new code in the question.

Comment: I tried the updated answer, but the image would still remain the same size. I finally solved the problem using @Martin Marconcini answer. Thanks for help!